# Potential of multiple network interfaces during RHEL deployment

Tags: networking, kickstart, provisioning

I want to deploy RHEL (6x64, though I think this should be applicable across versions) onto systems which may or may not have more than one NIC card.

Will kickstart error if I have multiple lines like

```
network --device=eth0 --bootproto=dhcp
network --device=eth1 --bootproto=dhcp
...
```

even if there is only one NIC on the host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specify the --device at all.

`network --bootproto=dhcp` should be enough.  In fact, bootproto=dhcp by default so you shouldn't even need a network line, assuming that the kickstart script is grabbed over the network (like when installing via PXE).

If you want to control what interface is being used on systems with multiple interfaces, take a look at the 'ksdevice' boot option.

References:
[Starting a Kickstart Install](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-startinginstall.html)

[Kickstart Options](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html)

Comment: That was my thinking, too, but only one adapter in a multiadapter system is getting an address

Comment: Why would you need more than one adapter to have an address during install?  I can understand the need to specify which (and you can with ksdevice), but multiple?

Comment: they're on different networks, and I want them to be up and running via dhcp from the get-go

Comment: I would just configure the interfaces in a post-install script.  They'll be ready and online after the install is complete.

Comment: that can lead to the adapters not being in a defined order (eth0..n), correct?

Comment: It could, but that's usually easily correctable.  Just need to set the correct name in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`.  In the most recent versions of RHEL / CentOS there is a new package called `biosdevname` that may be of help.  It's disabled by default except for a limited set of Dell servers, but the goal is consistent naming.  [Biosdevname - Consistent Network Device Naming](http://linux.dell.com/files/biosdevname/)